# javah в java 11

Tags: java, jni

В java 8 я использовал javah из папочки ${JAVA_HOME}/bin, а буквально недавно я обновился до Java 11 и там нет javah. В то же время я не могу использовать javah из Java 8 из-за несовместимости байт кода. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 4):

Читать [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9). Утилита javah объявлена устаревшей в Java 9 и удалена в java 10. Её заменяет добавленный в Java 8 ключ -h утилиты javac.